# how to calculate difference between two DateTime in ms?

Tags: c#

According to msdn DateTime precision is 10 ms. So `t2-t1` precision in the example below is also 10 ms. However the returned value is "double" what is confusing.

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now; // precision is 10 ms
....
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now; // precision is 10 ms
... (t2-t1).TotalMilliseconds; // double (so precision is less than 1 ms???)
```

I expect int value because double value doesn't make sense when precision is 10 ms. I need to use resulted value in Thread.Sleep(). Should I just cast to int?

Comment: It is just my curiosity. Which scenario needs a variable sleep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The precision of `DateTime` itself is down to the tick.

The granularity of `DateTime.Now` is typically 10 or 15ms - it's the granularity of the system clock. (That doesn't mean the clock is *accurate* to the nearest 10 or 15ms, mind you.) The subtraction operator on `DateTime` shouldn't know or care about that though - the result is just a `TimeSpan` which again has a precision to the tick level.

Just casting to `int` should be absolutely fine.

(You might want to read [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx) on this, by the way.)